# Regex for non commented method call in java code

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match a method call in my java code where the method call is not surrounded by any of the java comment types.

Actually, my requirement is to find all the java files where this method is called in a non-commented code.

For e.g., getMessage  is the method call, and provided the following code as input.. the RegEx should match only line #12.

```
// Systme.out.println (obj1.getMessage());  //line 1
/* Systme.out.println (obj.getMessage());*/ //line 2    
/* public void test() {                     //line 3    
   Systme.out.println (obj2.getMessage());  //line 4
   }                                        //line 5
*/                                          //line 6    
/**public void test () {                    //line 7
  * Systme.out.println (obj3.getMessage()); //line 8
  *}                                        //line 9
  */                                        //line 10
public void test() {                        //line 11
      Systme.out.println (obj5.getMessage());//line 12
 }
```

I first tried to match the negative cases i.e., method call within comments and then try to negate the expression. For that, i used.. `(?=(//|/*|*)).*getMessage.*` which would still not cover the method call at line #4.

But even before that.. when I used negative look around of above using `(?!(//|/*|*)).*getMessage.*`, it even started matching all the method calls. Then, I understood that am missing the concept of Atomic grouping and tried to explore it a bit but could not get much.

It would be appreciated much if you could help me in solving this. Thanks in advance,

PS : I only need the RegEx not the java code as I need to supply only the expression as input to the system.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Post your current regex and why you think it fails

Comment: Check http://regexpal.com/ and try something yourself

Comment: Using a regexp to do that is not a good idea, and it will not work, you need to write a parser. Here is the king of complexity you can get: `print("/*"); obj5.getMessage(); print("*/");`

Comment: Refrain from asking questions when you've not attempted to solve it yourself. The community here seems to get aggravated with questions that look like homework.

Comment: Hello @skamazin

I, first, tried to match the negative cases i.e., method call within comments and then try to negate the expression.
For that, i used.. "(?=(//|/\*|\*)).*getMessage.*" which would still not cover the method call at line #4.

But, even before that.. when i used negative look around of above using "(?!(//|/\*|\*)).*getMessage.*",
It even started matching all the method calls.

Then, I understood that am missing the concept of Atomic grouping and tried to explore it a bit but could not get much.

It would be appreciable if you could  help me in solving this.

Comment: Hi skamazin, any inputs? @jrharshath.. pls see my above comment provide your inputs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two stages

1. Remove everything in java file that is comment - eg everything between /* */ and every line that start with // + some exceptions
2. Run simple regex for method call eg. `.\w+?(.*|methodName).*;`

Comment: What if you have code like that: `print("/*"); obj5.getMessage(); print("*/");` ?

Comment: + some exceptions. All in all not task for pure regex

Comment: There are so many exception that you will end up writting a parser.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss, Thanks for your inputs. But, i don't have to edit the java files but just list all the files that have above mentioned usecase.